# jQuery load div element in the same domain but from another page?

Tags: jquery

I'am working on a script based on this: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Load the result:</b>
<div id="new-projects"></div>

<script>
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/ #page-header-container" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The element is in the same website but it's not loading.
You can see the result here: http://beta.sportsdirect.com/test/

I don't get it why, can anyone help me to resolve this problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the URL of the page in which the `div` element is?

Comment: The content of URL: http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/ doesn't have any element with id `page-header-container`

Comment: try this url http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/#header-search

Answer (score -1):

There is no element with "page-header-container" id in the page you wish to load the content from. This needs to be an id, not a class.